# sed does not replace

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I would like to get `>chr05_pilon_pilon.12.1` but unfortunately the below command does not remove the `t`

```
echo '>chr05_pilon_pilon.12.t1' | sed '/^\\>chr[0-9][0-9]_pilon_pilon/ s/\(.*\)t/\1/g'
>chr05_pilon_pilon.12.t1
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whenever you work with regular expressions, you should remember that "less is more". I mean you should always try to use the *simplest* and *shortest* pattern that matches your data. Don't try to match everything, only go for the part you actually need.

In this case, you have `>chr05_pilon_pilon.12.t1` and all you want to do is remove the last `t` after the last `.`. So don't try to match from the beginning, you don't care about that and it will only make your regular expression more complicated and easier to get wrong, as you did. Here are a few alternatives, depending on what you actually need:

1. Remove all non-numerical characters after the last `.` on lines starting with `>`:

   ```
    $ echo '>chr05_pilon_pilon.12.t1' | sed -E 's/^(>.*)\.[^0-9]*/\1./'
    >chr05_pilon_pilon.12.1
   ```
2. Remove the last `t` on lines starting with `>`:

   ```
    $ echo '>chr05_pilon_pilon.12.t1' | sed -E 's/^(>.*)t/\1/'
    >chr05_pilon_pilon.12.1
   ```
3. As above, but only if the `t` is immediately after a `.`

   ```
    $ echo '>chr05_pilon_pilon.12.t1' | sed -E 's/^(>.*\.)t/\1/'
    >chr05_pilon_pilon.12.1
   ```
4. Remove the last `t` that comes after a `.` but only on lines starting with `>` then `chr` followed by exactly two numbers and `pilon_pilon`:

   ```
    $ echo '>chr05_pilon_pilon.12.t1' | sed -E 's/^(>chr[0-9][0-9]_pilon_pilon.*\.)t/\1/'
    >chr05_pilon_pilon.12.1
   ```
5. Finally, assuming you might also have `X`, `Y` and `M` or `MT` chromosomes, you might want to extend the above to match on those as well

   ```
    $ printf '>chrX_pilon_pilon.12.t1\n>chr05_pilon_pilon.12.t1\n>chrMT_pilon_pilon.12.t1\n' |
         sed -E 's/^(>chr([0-9XYM]{1,2}|MT)_pilon_pilon.*\.)t/\1/'
    >chrX_pilon_pilon.12.1
    >chr05_pilon_pilon.12.1
    >chrMT_pilon_pilon.12.1
   ```

Answer (score 6):

Your pattern tries to match a `\` at the start of the line, which you don't have:

```
$ echo '>chr05_pilon_pilon.12.t1' | sed '/^\\>chr[0-9][0-9]_pilon_pilon/ s/\(.*\)t/\1/'
>chr05_pilon_pilon.12.t1
```

Without trying to match the `\` at the start of the line:

```
$ echo '>chr05_pilon_pilon.12.t1' | sed '/^>chr[0-9][0-9]_pilon_pilon/ s/\(.*\)t/\1/'
>chr05_pilon_pilon.12.1
```

You may possibly also want to allow for the X, Y, and possibly M chromosomes (depending on what your genome assembly contains):

```
echo '>chr05_pilon_pilon.12.t1' | sed -E '/^>chr([0-9][0-9]|[XYM])_pilon_pilon/ s/(.*)t/\1/'
```

Note too that `/g` is not needed.

Answer (score -1):

**This below command will help you to get the desired output**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo '>chr05_pilon_pilon.12.t1' | sed 's/.t/./'
```

**Output :**

```
 >chr05_pilon_pilon.12.1
```

Comment: That regular expression looks a little too enthusiastic; try `echo hot | sed s/.t/./`.

Comment: Did you mean `\.t`?

Comment: @TobySpeight   re - read the requirement , it clearly specifics need to remove `t`

Comment: @marcelm   re -read the requirement , it clearly specifics need to remove `t`

Comment: @codeholic24 Yes, but your regular expression pays no attention to the input structure; it'll remove the first `t` that's not the first character. I feel that's not robust enough. And if you really want to go that route, why not simply `s/t//`?

Comment: @marcelm  your point is right but why i have taken it like that because the requirement is like that to get rid of t from string , that too comes after the dot (.)  .. to be more specific i have written like that .. if their is another t like this ` >chr05_pilon_pilon.12t.t1
` your's will fail

Comment: @codeholic24 Just for fun, try out your regular expression on that input.

Comment: Requirement is not clear at all - is there a need to replace the character preceding `t` with `.`?  Who knows?  A much simpler solution satisfying the "requirement" is `echo '>chr05_pilon_pilon.12.1'`.  The best thing to do with such questions is to help improve them so they can be answered.